# NET::SSH multiple sequential SSH connections hangs at on_data. Is there a way to gracefully exit the infinite wait?

Tags: ruby, ssh, stdout, channel

I am trying to establish multiple ssh connections using the NET:SSH ruby gem to a host one at a time in sequential order. I am using the following code to do that. If I am trying making multiple connections(say 10000) to a host in this manner, the program hangs without any error. I am thinking that its because of the channel waiting on_data from reading input from the remote servers STDOUT. I am also thinking that when the STDOUT doesn't have any of these characters $%#> ( the prompt characters), it just waits. Is there a way to gracefully exit out of this state and continue to process the remaining transactions?

```
def ssh_session_to_remote
 cmd = "sudo /bin/su - user1"
  begin
   status = Timeout::timeout(300) do
     Net::SSH.start(host, username, :password => 'password') do |ssh|
       ssh.open_channel do |channel|
         channel.request_pty
         channel.exec(cmd);
         channel.on_data do |ch, data|
           if data =~ /[$%#>]/
            channel.send_data "cd /home/userX/data \n"
            channel.send_data "touch #{@file_name} \n"
            channel.send_data "echo \"#{@csv_string}\">>#{@file_name} \n"
            channel.send_data "exit \n"
            channel.send_data "\n~."
           end
      end
    end
  end
end
 rescue Timeout::Error
 puts "Timeout occurred"
 end
 @file_location = "/home/#{@remote_params[:username]}/data/#{@file_name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that adding a sleep of 1 to 2 seconds seems to solve the problem. I am sure there must be a better solution though.

```
def ssh_session_to_remote
 cmd = "sudo /bin/su - user1"
 begin
   status = Timeout::timeout(300) do
   Net::SSH.start(host, username, :password => 'password') do |ssh|
   ssh.open_channel do |channel|
     channel.request_pty
     channel.exec(cmd);
     channel.on_data do |ch, data|
       if data =~ /[$%#>]/
        channel.send_data "cd /home/userX/data \n"
        sleep 2
        channel.send_data "touch #{@file_name} \n"
        sleep 2
        channel.send_data "echo \"#{@csv_string}\">>#{@file_name} \n"
        sleep 2
        channel.send_data "exit \n"
        sleep 2
        channel.send_data "\n~."
       end
  end
end
 end
 end
   rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "Timeout occurred"
  end
   @file_location = "/home/#{@remote_params[:username]}/data/#{@file_name}"
   end
```